# Do i get a Android Broadcast or Event when the app comes back to focus

Tags: android

I want to be notified when my Android App comes back to focus or is started. The tricky part is, i don't care for the events which appear when switching Activities within the App. The Events i am interested in are:

- App is started
- App is reactivated on any Activity (brought back to front by the user)

I tried handling it with the `onStart()` and `onResume()` Methods, but they fire every time a `Activity` is loaded and call onStop even when they just switch Activities within the app

I checked the lifecycle (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) but even the `onDestroy()` is called when solely switching Activities within the App.

- How can i determine if my App is reactivated or just switching Activities?

Comment: Hmmmmm, just a thought, you could override the Application http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html    ,then register your applicationLifecycleCallbacks http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html and handle it in your application

Answer (score 0):

you have to override `Application` class for `**App is started**` this will call once every time when app is open.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions come to mind, neither of them is very clean.

**1) Use a timer**

Every time in your `onPause()` method, you schedule a timer that sets a flag after 1 Second (or something longer, depends on your exact use-case). In each `onResume()` you check if the flag has been set, e.g. your App has been inactive for longer than the timer interval. If the flag is set you know the user did something else between the `onPause()` and `onResume()`

**2) Set a flag manually**

Every time you trigger a switch between `Activities` in your App, you set a flag somewhere in your application. In your `onResume()` method, you check if the flag is set, e.g. the switch was triggered by your App. If it is not set, the user comes from outside of your App.

Both methods, however, can't discriminate any further between possible use-cases. All these cases will look the same to you:

- the user presses the home button and resumes the app at any given time later
- the user turns the screen off, and back on again
- the user gets a phone call and then immediatly returns to your app

This might lead to undesired behaviour of your App. I don't know what exactly you want to use this mechanism for, but you have to think very hard about all the possible cases, and if you want them to trigger your behaviour, or not.